# mysql - How to subtract from two queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have 2 queries from 2 tables(`purchase_products` & `sales_products`) and i want to subtract from first query quantity to second query quantity.

First Query:

```
$purchase_products = DB::table('purchase_products')
            ->join('products','products.id','purchase_products.product_id')
            ->select('products.product_name','purchase_products.purchase_price',DB::raw("SUM(purchase_products.quantity) as purchase_quantity"))
            ->groupby('purchase_products.product_id','purchase_products.purchase_price')
            ->get();
```

Second Query:

```
 $sales_products = DB::table('sales_products')
            ->select('sales_products.purchase_price',DB::raw("SUM(sales_products.quantity) as sales_quantity"))
            ->groupby('sales_products.product_id','sales_products.purchase_price')
            ->get();
```

How do i subtract only quantity from second query and keep as it is of first query?

```
unique column: product_id & purchase_price
```

Comment: What each query gives out as a result?

Comment: join both queiries a subqueries on product_id and subtract

Comment: can you just with example please? @nbk

Answer (score 0):

According to laravel documentation you can join two or more queries tables by joinSub, leftJoinSub, and rightJoinSub.
you can see example in
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#subquery-joins
for substration you can use joinSub